# Thin Out Controller in Asp.Net-Mvc-5 Specific Example

Tags: c#, design-patterns, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question regarding the implementation of creating "thin controllers" in an Asp.net Mvc 5 application. I've researched this topic for the past couple of days, and I believe I'm at the point where I need a concrete example in order to connect the dots in my understanding.

So, I would like to make use of Unit tests in my application. I've looked at creating view model factories, and builders, skinny controller-fat model, but I'm not quire sure how to implement any of these design patterns that I've read about in this particular scenario.

Below you'll find 5 different actions that are found in my Manage controller. I fear that they smell and require some clean up for simplifying testing/unit testing. I understand that there is usually no "right answer" to these type of questions, so I would greatly appreciate all answers that aid in simplifying testing my application.

Here are my actions:

Action #1:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "DM_Admin")]

public async Task<ActionResult> Users_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ManageUsersViewModel model)

{
    if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // instantiate new application user
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName
        };

        // format the RolesList to type List<string> for entry  
        List<string> rolesToAssign = getRoleNameList(model);

        try
        {
            // persist user to User Db
            var createResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (createResult.Succeeded)
            {
                // persist user roles to User Db
                var rolesResult = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, rolesToAssign.ToArray());
                if (rolesResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ManageUsers");
                }
                AddErrors(rolesResult);
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(createResult);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrLog.LogError(ex, "ManageController.Users_Create");
        }
    }

    return Json(new[] { model }.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Action #2:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "DM_Admin")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Users_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)

{
    List<ManageUsersViewModel> users = null;
List<ApplicationUser> allUsers = null;

try
{
    // get all Data Management roles
    var dmRoles = await RoleManager.Roles.Where(r => r.Name.Contains("DM_")).ToListAsync();

    // find all the users for each Data Management role
    foreach (var id in dmRoles.Select(r => r.Id).ToList())
    {
        if(allUsers == null)
        {
            allUsers = await UserManager.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == id)).ToListAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            allUsers.AddRange(await UserManager.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == id)).ToListAsync());
        }
    }

    // list of users may have repeats, so remove repeated users in list 
    allUsers = allUsers.Distinct().ToList();
    // instantiate view model with list of users and their respective roles
    users = allUsers.Select(u => new ManageUsersViewModel
    {
        Id = u.Id,
        FirstName = u.FirstName,
        LastName = u.LastName,
        Email = u.Email,
        Password = u.PasswordHash,
        ConfirmPassword = u.PasswordHash,
        RolesList = dmRoles.Where(r => r.Users.Any(user => user.UserId == u.Id)).Select(r => new RoleModel
                {
                    Id = r.Id,
                    Name = r.Name
                }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ErrLog.LogError(ex, "ManageController.Users_Read");
}

return Json(users.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Action #3:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "DM_Admin")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Users_Edit([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ManageUsersViewModel model)
{
    if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // format the RolesList to type List<string> with name and List<string> with Id for entry and comparison
        List<string> rolesToAssign = getRoleNameList(model);
        List<string> modelRoleIds = getRoleIdList(model);
    try
    {
        var currentUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id);
        // create list of current user's roles to determine if they have been modified
        List<string> currentUserRoleIds = new List<string>();
        foreach (var role in currentUser.Roles)
        {
            currentUserRoleIds.Add(role.RoleId);
        }

        // persist user roles to User Db if changes have been made
        if (currentUserRoleIds.Except(modelRoleIds).Any() || modelRoleIds.Except(currentUserRoleIds).Any())
        {
            var updateRolesResult = await AssignRolesToUser(model.Id, rolesToAssign.ToArray());
            if (updateRolesResult.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ManageUsers", new { Message = ManageMessageId.AccountUpdateSuccess });
            }
            AddErrors(updateRolesResult);
        }
        // persist user info to User Db if changes have been made
        else if(currentUser.Email != model.Email || currentUser.FirstName != model.FirstName || currentUser.LastName != model.LastName)
        {
            currentUser.UserName = model.Email;
            currentUser.Email = model.Email;
            currentUser.FirstName = model.FirstName;
            currentUser.LastName = model.LastName;

            var updateUserResult = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(currentUser);
            if (updateUserResult.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ManageUsers", new { Message = ManageMessageId.AccountUpdateSuccess });
            }
            AddErrors(updateUserResult);
        }
        // persist user password to User Db if changes have been made
        else
        {
            var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(currentUser.Id);
            var updatePasswordResult = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(currentUser.Id, token, model.Password);
            if (updatePasswordResult.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ManageUsers", new { Message = ManageMessageId.AccountUpdateSuccess });
            }
            AddErrors(updatePasswordResult);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrLog.LogError(ex, "ManageController.Users_Edit");
    }
}

return Json(new[] { model }.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Action #4:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "DM_Admin")] 
public async Task<ActionResult> Users_Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ManageUsersViewModel model)
{
    if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // format the RolesList to type List<string> for removal  
        List<string> rolesToRemove = getRoleNameList(model);
    try
    {
        // get the user to be deleted by id
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id);

        // remove roles from user in User Db
        var removeRolesResult = await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user.Id, rolesToRemove.ToArray());
        if (removeRolesResult.Succeeded)
        {
            // remove user from User Db
            var removeUserResult = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            if (removeUserResult.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ManageUsers", new { Message = ManageMessageId.AccountDeleteSuccess });
            }
            AddErrors(removeUserResult);
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(removeRolesResult);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrLog.LogError(ex, "ManageController.Users_Delete");
    }
}

return Json(new[] { model }.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Action #5:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "DM_Admin")] 
public async Task<IdentityResult> AssignRolesToUser(string id, string[] rolesToAssign)
{
    if (rolesToAssign != null)
    {
        try
        {
            // find the user to assign roles to
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (user != null)
            {
                // check if the user currently has any roles
                var currentRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
                var rolesNotExist = rolesToAssign.Except(RoleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name)).ToArray();
            if (!(rolesNotExist.Count() > 0))
            {
                // remove current roles from user, if any, in User Db
                var removeRolesResult = await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user.Id, currentRoles.ToArray());
                if (!removeRolesResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    AddErrors(removeRolesResult);
                    return removeRolesResult;
                }

                // assign new roles to user in User Db
                var addRolesResult = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, rolesToAssign);
                if (!addRolesResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    AddErrors(addRolesResult);
                }
                return addRolesResult;
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Roles '{0}' do not exist in the system", string.Join(",", rolesNotExist)));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Unable to find user"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrLog.LogError(ex, "ManageController.AssignRolesToUser");
    }
}
else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("No roles specified"));
}
return null;
}
```

I kept the Identity framework the same as how Microsoft sets it up when creating a default Mvc application, and because of this I'm not really sure how to go about refactoring the code.

I understand this is a longer post, so thank you so much for taking the time to read it and I hope to hear from you all soon.

**Note: I added 5 action methods because I believe they may be necessary to show in order to thin out the controller as a whole, along with giving a better understanding of whats going on. But please don't feel the need to provide examples for all of the actions listed. **

Thanks so much guys!
Snawwz

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to code review as it is code that works and does not have a specific problem that requires solving. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Using a 'handler' approach with Mediatr can work well: https://jonhilton.net/2016/06/06/simplify-your-controllers-with-the-command-pattern-and-mediatr/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're committing the cardinal sin of the new developer: getting stuck in pattern hell, instead of just worrying about your application.

Design patterns are just recommended ways of solving particular kinds of problems. Enough developers have done the same thing enough times to sort of congeal on an accepted set of best practices. However, what often gets lost in this is that design patterns exist to solve specific types of problems. If your app doesn't have that particular problem, there's no need to implement that particular pattern. You see this far too often with the use of the repository pattern with an ORM like Entity Framework. The repository pattern exists to shuffle all the raw SQL code using a database directly requires all into on tidy place. If you don't have raw SQL code lying around *you don't need the repository pattern*.

Further, the needs of the application outweighs any "best practice". For example, very few would argue that you *shouldn't* implement inversion of control and dependency injection in your application. In 99.999% of applications, that improves your application dramatically. However, the Stack Overflow Core team does not use it at all. Why? Because, it adds heft to the application. The Core team's sole responsibility to is to make Stack Overflow as performant as possible, and in this particular application dependency injection doesn't work.

The point of all this is to just build your app. Don't worry about everything being correct or every "best practice" being followed. Just build it. Then, you can go back and refactor, and as you refactor, you'll find opportunities to do things in a better way. At that point, you can refer to the various design patterns for guidance. Trying to worry about all this stuff right at the beginning is a trap that will far too often leave you frozen in your tracks, incapable of moving forward.

One further note: you need to allow yourself time and freedom to become experienced. What I mean by that is that, once you become experienced at doing this stuff, you'll do things how they should be done right out of the gate, because it starts to become second nature. However, you have to get to that point, first. There's no shame in your code not being perfect when you're first starting out. I don't know a single developer who wouldn't shudder if they were confronted with the code they wrote when they were newbies. As you build more applications, contront new challenges, solve new problems, etc. you'll build up a knowledge-base that will make it much easier to do the right thing. Give yourself some breathing room.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your time Chris. As I'm just starting out my career, this type of answer is both really insightful and reassuring. I appreciate you!

Comment: Yes, *[premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)*

Answer (score 0):

Basically MVC is a presentation pattern. It was/is not designed to be a panacea to all design problems. It should only format data for the user(s) to view. No more, no less.

It should only take data, pass it to a rendering engine (Razor) and create routes (that's it). Everything else should be in other layers/patterns. This is the crux of "Skinny controllers", they are skinny because they contain zero logic (presentation pattern remember). What these "other" patterns should be is totally up to your situation. There is no one solution to this problem.

To provide an example of a skinny controller from your examples it'd look **something** like this:

```
private MyLogicClass _logic;

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "DM_Admin")] 
public async Task<ActionResult> Users_Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ManageUsersViewModel model)
{
    var model = _logic.DoLogic();
    return View(model);
}
```

all the "stuff" in your examples should reside inside one or more "logic classes", `MyLogicClass` in the example above. Your controllers should be very dumb and just pass data around.

Comment: Thanks for the input Liam!

Comment: It's a good practice but what's wrong with fat controllers anyway? You can always refactor that later if there's a need or you see that you have a repeating code.

Comment: I would focus on getting something to work first putting everything in controllers and then if I felt it's wrong I would move it out of there. Always try to find a reason first, separating it just for the sake of separation is just a waste of time

Comment: Like I often see people separating projects but they only reference it in one project. When this could be easily put in a separate folder not project.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with fat controllers and it makes it easier to start with. Think of controller's actions as of remote procedures.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Konrad!